# Implement custom Authentication, AuthenticationFilter and AuthenticationProvider in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The objective is to get a session token from the header in my custom authentication filter. Build my custom authentication object where I can pass the session token as a name. This custom authentication object will be passed to my custom authentication provider class, where I want to build an authentication object if the session token is valid.

Custom Authentication object

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationObject implements Authentication{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private Object credentials;
    private Object details;
    private Object principal;
    private boolean authenticated;
}
```

Custom Filter to get token from the header and build Authentication object for passing it to AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SessionTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Inside session filter");
        String sessionToken = request.getHeader("session-token");
        log.info("Session token " + sessionToken);
        if (sessionToken != null) {
            AuthenticationObject authentication = new AuthenticationObject();
            authentication.setName(sessionToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Custom AuthenticationProvider to validate session token and pass Authentication object

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SessionAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        log.info("Authentication token " + authentication.getName());
        AuthenticationObject authenticationObject = new AuthenticationObject();
        authenticationObject.setName("Harsh");
        authenticationObject.setAuthenticated(true);
        authenticationObject.setAuthorities(Collections.<GrantedAuthority>emptyList());
        return authenticationObject;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return AutenticationObject.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

Configuring SecurityFilterChain to secure all my API endpoints and invoking my custom filter. Injecting my custom AuthenticationProvider implementation inside AuthenticationManager.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private SessionTokenFilter sessionTokenFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(sessionTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = 
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke any API endpoint I get 403. Below is the trace log of spring security classes

```
2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /api/contenteditor/feed/5
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 83FA8B6A615DD9898C33EF9B98BCC479 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SessionTokenFilter (6/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.254[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.w.presto.security.SessionTokenFilter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Inside session filter
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.255[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.w.presto.security.SessionTokenFilter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Session token 12345
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.256[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.256[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.256[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:6060/presto-boot/api/contenteditor/feed/5
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=83FA8B6A615DD9898C33EF9B98BCC479], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequestAwareWrapper@6aa7ef6a]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.257[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequestAwareWrapper@6aa7ef6a] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6e9866e6
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=83FA8B6A615DD9898C33EF9B98BCC479], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at com.wf.presto.security.SessionTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionTokenFilter.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Saved request http://localhost:6060/presto-boot/api/contenteditor/feed/5 to session
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not store empty SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not store empty SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.260[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4ae2b686, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4b15617a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@37cbe1e9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2b6c24bf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1632f898, com.wf.presto.security.SessionTokenFilter@b4e0b59, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6a05b84a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@20862069, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@ccfc0c1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b82b88a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@46736c06, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@40a632cb]] (1/1)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /error
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 83FA8B6A615DD9898C33EF9B98BCC479 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SessionTokenFilter (6/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not match request /error to the saved one DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost:6060/presto-boot/api/contenteditor/feed/5]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=83FA8B6A615DD9898C33EF9B98BCC479], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /error
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authorizing org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation$DummyRequest@4f725109
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Checking authorization on org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation$DummyRequest@4f725109 using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6e9866e6
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-02-17 14:10:22.261[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m23496[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-6060-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Removed authenticationprovider from SecurityConfiguration class I have created.

Made changes in my SessionTokenFilter class

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SessionTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Inside session filter");
        String sessionToken = request.getHeader("session-token");
        log.info("Session token " + sessionToken);
        if (sessionToken != null) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(sessionToken, "Pwd");
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            context.setAuthentication(authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication));
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```